# Slanted Div Not Correct

Tags: html, css

I have been recently creating a website, but I want the html at the top of my website to be split in half diagonally, one half gray, the other half white. I have no clue how to do that. I looked at other stack overflow questions on this and tried to use there answers, but couldn't figure out how too. Here is my code, can you help me? JSFIDDLE LINK: http://jsfiddle.net/j4rtcfm0/

```
<div id="supercollosalDiv" style="border: 10px solid black; border-radius: 70px;">
<div style="font-weight: bold; background-color: gray; text-align: center;"><span style="" onclick="click3()">Where Everything Is Clickable</span><img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/shopping-cart-icon-flat-design-260nw-570153007.jpg" width="20px" style="padding-left: 10px;" onclick="cart()"><span><div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 20px; margin-top: 10px;">
  <button class="dropbtn">Account</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="delete_account()">Delete Account</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="info()">Account Information</a>
  </div>
</div></span></div>
<div id="signin" style="text-align: center; background-color: gray; padding-top: 10px; color: blue; font-weight: bold; padding-right: -80px;">You are NOT signed in. Click <button id="blaha" onclick="si()" style="background-color: transparent; border: 0px solid gray; font-size: 15px; color: blue; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">here</button> to sign in</div>
<div style="background-color: grey; text-align: center;">
<div id="signin2" style="text-align: center; background-color: gray; padding-top: 10px; color: blue; font-weight: bold; display: none; position: relative; padding-right: 80px;">Great Job!! You ARE signed in.</div>
<div style="background-color: grey; text-align: center;">
<br>
<button style="position: relative; bottom: 110px; left: 60px; border-radius: 10px; color: white; background-color: black; border: 2px solid gray;" id="blaha8" onclick="si()">Sign in</button>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/1200px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png" width="50px" style="display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 10px; margin-right: 20px;" onclick="menu_button_clicked()" id="menu">
<header style="position: fixed; font-size: 50px; display: inline-block; position: relative; margin-right: 50px;" onclick="home()" id="Ramdon">WorldWeb</header>
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for items.."title="Type in a name" style="display: inline-block; position: relative; top: -10px; right: 30px; border: 3px solid black;" onkeyup="show()">
<img src="https://static.thenounproject.com/png/3134345-200.png" style="width: 30px; position: relative; top: 0px; right: 30px;" onclick="search()" id="search">
<img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/14/14980.png" width="10px" style="float: right; position: absolute; text-align: center;" onclick="new_product()">
<div style="font-size: 10px; position: relative; left: -220px; top: 10px; display: inline-block;" id="all" onclick="show_all_products()">All Products (That haven't been deleted)</div>
<br><br><br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

You need to have a width of approximately 800 px to view it correctly. Thanks in advance!!

This is what it should look like, minus the text. Also it should be split in half diagonally, point to point :

[image: exemple picture]

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: You mean here by in the comments, or in the actual question.

Comment: In the question, we have to be able to see a working example of your problem. Try to reproduce it by copy and paste your code into a snippet here or on services like Codepen or Jsfiddle.

Comment: Done, added a link.

Comment: Please, do yourself a favor and stop using inline `style=""`. Use a stylesheet instead. Also, learn some basics about web/app design.

Comment: check this out (not my own pen): https://codepen.io/alivim/pen/ZvdBWd

Comment: Yes, I get that, but how do I add text within it?